# What are some common Chinese terms used when playing soccer

Tags: vocabulary

I regularly play soccer with a group of Chinese guys and wanted to share terms that I've learnt over the years.

I would appreciate if anyone can fill in any gaps (or correct me if I'm wrong).

Comment: While the spirit of this question is good, the way it is posed and subsequently answered is not really a good format to display as an early question.  Please consider reformulating the question, maybe along the lines of "What are common Chinese terms used when playing football(soccer)?"

Comment: Actually, I don't know some terms in English, so I can't give you more terms.I think you can get more terms by googling on the Internet and I added a link of a website to my answer.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Red Card: 红牌 *hóngpái*

Yellow card: 黄牌 *huángpái*

Shoot: 射 (射门) *shè (shèmén)*

Pass: 传 (传球) *chuán (chuán qiú)*

Goal: 门 （球门) *mén (qiú mén)*

Referee: 裁判 *cáipàn*

Half time: 半场 *bàn chǎng*

Full time: 全场 *quán chǎng* or 结束了 or 踢好了

Team: 队 （蓝队， 白队 etc.) *duì*

The ball has gone out: 出界

Did the ball go in?: 球进了没有?

Are you injured?: （受）伤了没有？

Kick off: 开球

Pitch: 球场

Substitution: 换人

Score: 比分

1:0 (one to zero) :  一比零

Offside: 越位

Penalty area: 禁区

Overtime: 加时

Golden goal: 金球

Silver goal: 银球

Front-field: 前场

Midfield: 中场

Backfield: 后场

Handball: 手球

Header: 头球

Foul: 犯规

Preliminary match: 预赛

Eighth-final: 八分之一决赛

Quarter-final: 四分之一决赛

Semi-final: 半决赛

Final: 决赛

Comment: This seems to be a good candidate for wiki.

Comment: @StarCub - CW happens automatically if enough people add to (edit) the answer. I have manually switched it CW.

Answer (score 1):

Coach: 教练 *jiàoliàn*

Corner kick: 角球 *jiǎoqiú*

Penalty kick: 点球 *diǎn qiú*

Player: 球员 *qiúyuán*

Free kick: 任意球 *rènyì qiú*

**EDIT: A link for you to get more terms**
I find a [website](http://events.sparke.cn/digieng/zqyy/) where you can learn more terms in football game. It's displays a swf animation and is funny.